# What do these 2 code fragments do

Tags: math

These 2 code fragments from the book Algorithms seem to be doing something mathematical. The code I have no trouble understanding, but I want to know what mathematical computation is being done.

1.

```
double t=c;
while(Math.abs(t-c/t) > 1e-15*t) 
    t=(c/t+t)/2.0;
```

2.

```
for(int i=0;i<=N;i++)
    StdOut.println(2*Math.Pi*i/N);
    // prints the value of circumference of a circle of radius 0, 1/N,2/N .. 1 ?
```

Comment: Tag the language the code is written in. Java, maybe?

Comment: ...that said, as a rule, "identify X" isn't generally a very welcome variety of question. Nobody else is likely to have the same X, and even if they did, they couldn't identify that your question was asking about the same algorithms by looking at the question title in search results. A good StackOverflow question *is useful to more people than just you* -- meaning it isolates a question that's likely to help other people, and uses a title and searchable terms that will help those hypothetical people find it when they have the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first is a standard algorithm for [approximating square roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots). It can be viewed as a special case of Newton's method but was known thousands of years before Newton and is sometimes called the Babylonian algorithm. The second really should be self-explanatory as it is commented and is just an immediate application of the definition of `pi` as the ration of circumference to diameter, which is twice the radius.

Comment: Thanks for the telling me. I put the comment myself. Is the second one just printing circumferences of circles?

Comment: @Johnson Yes, that is all that it is doing

Comment: @RoryDaulton Good point. For some reason that special case popped in mind when I saw that fragment. Thanks.